# How to find this limit to infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to calculate the limit
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\sqrt{\left|\frac{t}{n^2}\right|\left(2-\left|\frac{t}{n^2}\right|\right)}\right)^n$$
I think that maybe L'hopithal works with:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\sqrt{\left|\frac{t}{n^2}\right|\left(2-\left|\frac{t}{n^2}\right|\right)}\right)^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{n\cdot \ln\left(1-\sqrt{|\frac{t}{n^2}|(2-|\frac{t}{n^2}|}\right)}$$
but  I don't find that.

Comment: It should be $e^{-\sqrt{ 2|t|} }$.

Comment: How did you do the last step? It isn't true that $\;e^{nh}=\frac{e^h}{e^{-n}}\;$ ...

Comment: terrible undescriptive title. -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[1-\sqrt{\left|\frac{t}{n^2}\right|\left(2-\left|\frac{t}{n^2}\right|\right)}\right]^n=\left[1-\frac{\sqrt{\left|t\right|\left(2-\left|\frac{t}{n^2}\right|\right)}}{n}\right]^n=e^{-\sqrt{2|t|}}$$

using that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=L\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{f(x_n)}n\right)^n=e^L\;,\;\;L<\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n = \sqrt{(|t|/n^2)(2- |t|/n^2)}= n^{-1}\sqrt{|t|(2-|t|/n^2)}.$

Note that $a_n \to 0$ and $a_n < 1$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

Hence $n\ln (1-a_n) = -n(a_n + O(a_n^2)) \to -\sqrt{2|t|},$

and $$(1 - a_n)^n \to e^{-\sqrt{2|t|}}$$

Alternatively, using the inequality $-x > \ln(1-x) > -x/(1-x)$ for $0 < x < 1$,

$$-na_n > n\ln(1-a_n) > \frac{-na_n}{1-a_n},$$

and $n\ln(1-a_n)\to -\sqrt{2|t|}$ follows from the squeeze theorem.